# JQuery: nesting if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```
if ( window.matchMedia( '( max-width: 1000px )' ).matches ) {
    $( mobilemenuopenwhitewide ).css( 'display' , 'block' ).css( 'top' , 15 ).css( 'opacity' , 1 );
    $( mobilemenuopenblackwide ).css( 'display' , 'block' ).css( 'top' , 15 ).css( 'opacity' , 1 );
} else {
    $( mobilemenuopenwhitewide ).css( 'display' , 'none' );
    $( mobilemenuopenblackwide ).css( 'display' , 'none' );
}
```

I'd like to amend this script so that the if statement includes BOTH when the window is less than 1000px AND when some other element has a certain attribute like $( apple ).css( 'z-index' , 500 ). I've tried doing:

```
if ( window.matchMedia( '( max-width: 1000px )' ).matches && $(apple).css('z-index',500) ) {
```

but that doesn't work so what am I to do?

Comment: What is `$(apple)`?  If 'apple` is the id, try `$('#apple')`

Comment: It's a variable but either way, doesn't work for me. Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are setting z-index to 500.

```
$(apple).css('z-index',500)
```

You wanted to do:

```
$(apple).css('z-index') == 500
```